# Quitar los null en una consulta y agrupar

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo la siguiente tabla llamada **mdatos**

```
id  M1      MOBJETO     MDATOS
1   100     NOMBRE      JUAN
2   100     APELLIDO    PEREZ
3   100     CORREO      JP@GMAIL.COM
4   200     NOMBRE      JUAN
5   200     APELLIDO    PEREZ
6   200     CORREO      JP@GMAIL.COM
7   300     NOMBRE      JUAN
8   300     APELLIDO    PEREZ
9   300     CORREO      JP@GMAIL.COM
```

Tengo otra tabla llamada **mseccion**

```
M1
100
200
300
```

la columna **m1** de la tabla **mseccion** es **primary key** y es **foreing key** de **mdatos**

Tengo el siguiente query

```
SELECT a.m1,
   CASE  B.mobjeto WHEN 'NOMBRE' THEN B.mdatos ELSE NULL END AS NOMBRE,
   CASE  B.mobjeto WHEN 'APELLIDO' THEN B.mdatos ELSE NULL END AS APELLIDO,
   CASE  B.mobjeto WHEN 'EMAIL' THEN B.mdatos ELSE NULL END AS EMAIL
FROM MSECCION AS A
LEFT JOIN MDATOS AS B ON A.M1 = B.M1
GROUP BY a.m1, B.mobjeto, B.mdatos
```

y me arroja lo siguiente

```
M1      NOMBRE      APELLIDO    EMAIL
100     JUAN        NULL        NULL
300     NULL        NULL        PF@GMAIL.COM
200     MARIA       NULL        NULL
100     NULL        PEREZ       NULL
300     PEDRO       NULL        NULL
300     NULL        FLORES      NULL
200     NULL        TORRES      NULL
100     NULL        NULL        JP@GMAIL.COM
200     NULL        NULL        MT@GMAIL.COM
```

Como haria o que me falta para que me quede asi?

```
M1      NOMBRE      APELLIDO    EMAIL
100     JUAN        PEREZ       JP@GMAIL.COM
200     MARIA       TORRES      MT@GMAIL.COM
300     PEDRO       FLORES      PF@GMAIL.COM
```

Comment: Y el `Where` para filtrar los que sean distintos de null?

Comment: mis tablas no tienen registros en null, es la consulta quien me lo da, por ende no puedo filtrar algun campo que sea distinto a null

Comment: Inserta el resultado en una tabla temporal y luego haces el filtrado de los nulls.

Comment: No creo que insertando eso en una tabla temporal sea lo mas viable y optimo, pues creo que mi problema esta en el query y necesito mejorarlo, ademas ese query lo llevare a un lenguaje de programacion

Comment: Estas tratando de hacer una tabla pivotante.. busca sobre eso ;)

Comment: @gbianchi, desconozco sobre pivotant, apesar de que me ayudaron voy a investigar lo que me indicas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pareciera que simplemente necesitas usar una función de agregación y agrupar por menos columnas:

```
SELECT a.m1,
   MIN(CASE  B.mobjeto WHEN 'NOMBRE' THEN B.mdatos ELSE NULL END) AS NOMBRE,
   MIN(CASE  B.mobjeto WHEN 'APELLIDO' THEN B.mdatos ELSE NULL END) AS APELLIDO,
   MIN(CASE  B.mobjeto WHEN 'EMAIL' THEN B.mdatos ELSE NULL END) AS EMAIL
FROM MSECCION AS A
LEFT JOIN MDATOS AS B ON A.M1 = B.M1
GROUP BY 
    a.m1
```

Comment: @Lamax, gracias esto era lo que buscaba.